# angular bootstrap getelmentbyId is returning NULL

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I want to use Bootstrap spinner in Angular before a table is populated.
But in my .ts file GetElementById is returning NULL value.

Below is my .html and .ts code.

.Html code:

```
<div class="spinner-border" role="Status" >
    <span class="sr-only" id="Loading"></span>
</div>
```

.ts Code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {

this._StudentService.getStudentList().
subscribe(data => {
  if(data){
    HideLoader();
  }
  console.log('data received',data);
  this.StudentList = data;
},
err =>{
        console.log('err getting students data',err)
      });
      const value=document.getElementById('loading');
 
      function HideLoader(){
        document.getElementById('loading')!.style.display = 'none';
      }
}
```

Comment: as pbachman said you don't need to use getElementById in angular. But the reason this doesn't work is because id:s are case sensitive, and in your HTML code you have a capitalized L in Loading, while you don't in your ts code.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to use getElementById within angular. you could use the ngIf directive (see https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) to hide or show the loading spinner.

```
<div class="spinner-border" role="Status" *ngIf="loading">
    <span class="sr-only"></span>
</div>
```

Component (don't forget to create a loading variable)

```
loading: boolean;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.loading = true;  
  this._StudentService.getStudentList().subscribe(data => {
    console.log('data received',data);
    this.StudentList = data;
    this.loading = false; 
  },
  err =>{
    this.loading = false;            
    console.log('err getting students data',err)
  });
```

Comment: I have modified my.html as suggested with *ngIf, but now not getting the 'loading' intellicence when I type 'this.' in .ts code.

Comment: @PradeepKumar have you declare the loading variable (above the ngOnInit method) ? loading: boolean;

Comment: Thanks @pbachman for guiding.

I have done the following changes.

as suggested I have added loading!: Boolean; before ngOnInit.

Note: B is capital in Boolean.

Comment: @PradeepKumar i've updated the answer, please check my code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks  @pbachman for guiding.

I have done the following changes.

as suggested I have added `loading!: Boolean;` before ngOnInit.

Note: B is capital in Boolean.